# Database and Hibernate Entity field type missmatch

Tags: java, database, hibernate, liquibase

Let's say I have a table in the database:

```
Table: Test
- type: smallint, field name: field1
```

And I created a Hibernate Entity for it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Test")
public class TableTest {
    @Column(name = "field1")
    private int field1 = 0;
}
```

Database is being initialized using Liquibase, so `hibernate.autoDdl` is off. Let's say it worked for some time, but then after this field tried to update to the value bigger than 2 bytes it raised exception because there is a type missmatch: in the database the field has `smallint` type (2 bytes), while in Entity it's `int` (4 bytes). Let's say the program was already running for some time, so database contains info and e.t.c., so it wouldn't be the best idea to change type in the database and init liquibase scripts, right? Is it okay if I will just change the type of the field in the Hibernate Entity to `short`, it shouldn't somehow affect the database itself so nothing crucial will happen, right?

Comment: Nothing crucial will happen, it's true. But are you so sure that there would not be values that cant be put inside smallint? if you doubt I recommend a liquibase column type change script.

Comment: did you resolve it?